# Bloquear commits no GitHub

Tags: git, github

Eu tenho um repositório no GitHub e recentemente meu amigo amigo também começou a me ajudar nesse repositório, queria saber se tem como eu rejeitar os commits dele ou algo do tipo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você adicionou ele como colaborador, você não pode rejeitar. 
Se ele não for colaborador, ele tem que fazer um Pull Request com o commit dele e você como dono do repositório pode aceitar ou não.

Comment: Vixe, vou ter que pedir pra ele fazer o Pull Request, ele não pode adicionar contribuíres certo ?

Comment: É, colaborador não tem permissão pra alterar as configurações do repositório.